# Displaying the form in center in c#

Tags: c#

i am new here, actually i am working on project which is in c#, and in that project i want to display my form in the center of the screen... So for that i have written the following code..

```
public class CenterForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
private System.ComponentModel.Container components;

public CenterForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    CenterToScreen();
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        if (components != null)
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}

private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // button1
    // 
    this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(107, 177);
    this.button1.Name = "button1";
    this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
    this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
    this.button1.Text = "Ok";
    this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    // 
    // CenterForm
    // 
    this.AutoScaleBaseSize = new System.Drawing.Size(5, 13);
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 273);
    this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
    this.Name = "CenterForm";
    this.Text = "DataGridExample";
    this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.CenterForm_Paint);
    this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.CenterForm_Resize);
    this.ResumeLayout(false);

}
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.Run(new CenterForm());
}
private void CenterForm_Resize(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Invalidate();
    Console.WriteLine("Resize");
}
private void CenterForm_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    g.DrawString("Text",
      new Font("Times New Roman", 20),
      new SolidBrush(Color.Black),
      this.DisplayRectangle);
}

private Button button1;
}
```

but it is giving some errors,that are
1)Error 1   'center.Form1.Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to override  C:\Users\logicwaves\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\center\center\Form1.Designer.cs   14  33  center

2)Error 2   Program 'C:\Users\logicwaves\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\center\center\obj\Debug\center.exe' has more than one entry point defined: 'center.Program.Main()'   C:\Users\logicwaves\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\center\center\Program.cs  13  21  center

3)Error 3   Program 'C:\Users\logicwaves\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\center\center\obj\Debug\center.exe' has more than one entry point defined: 'CenterForm.Main()'   C:\Users\logicwaves\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\center\center\Form1.cs    58  17  center

what should i do, to overcome from these errors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

no need for that  `CenterForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;`

Answer (score 2):

The errors are because you defined `Main()` method in the Form.cs class. Normally it will be in the Program.cs class, if you are using Visual Studio. `Dispose()` method may available in the Form.Designer.cs too. You can make the form center of the screen by setting the `StartPosition` property to `FormStartPosition.CenterScreen`;

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`this` ***meant by current Form***

```
this.CenterToScreen();
```

Answer (score -3):

1.Open .cs file in Notepad

2.Now (ctr+A) select all and delete(you can't see any text)

3.type the following code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace **[Namespace of your form]**
{
    public partial class [class name of your form]: Form
    {
        public [class name of your form]()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }       
    }
}
```

Its realy working ...

Comment: No, it's not 'really working'. It's throwing away the baby with the bathwater.

Comment: I want to point something out here. While this answer is obviously technically correct, it is still an answer, and should not have been flagged in the first place.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII This answer got flagged? No, it definitely should not have been flagged (assuming it was flagged as 'not an answer')